# Jenkins Declarative Pipelines: How to rename "Declarative: Post Actions" step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline which looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    stages {...}
    post {
        success {...}
        failure {...}
    }
}
```

It leads to creation of a last step called "Declarative: Post Actions".

**Q:** How to rename the "Declarative: Post Actions" step?

I would like to have a meaningful name like "Send Email Notifications".

[image: pipeline]

**UPDATE:**

The names [are hardcoded in this class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/pipeline-model-api/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/SyntheticStageNames.java). With the current version of the API (3.44) it is not possible to rename them.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do too

Comment: @ChrisR take a look at my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've looked in the Jenkins backlog to see if there's anything for this but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you like short stage names, like me, "Notify" would be a good name.  Goes with "Init", "Build", "Test", "Publish", etc.

Comment: Your update that "It's not possible" would make for a good (self-answer) to this question.

Comment: Instead of updating your original post with the answer please post this as an answer and self select it

Answer (score 1):

Move `post` part into a stage.
Stages has post section the same way as the whole pipeline has.